# Changes in Visual Studio 2008 not 'taking'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I've been consistently having a problem where changes I make to my web form or code-behind doesn't get recognized by the debugger until I quit visual studio and delete the "root" folder  located in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files.

It's very cumbersome and greatly decreases my productivity.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've tried reinstalling visual studio, using visual studio 2010 and a variety of other proposed solutions.

Thanks very much

Update: On a hunch, I moved the project to the C: drive.  (It was residing on a network drive)
No difference.

I added a control as a test and ran the program.  Label shows up.  Deleted the label.  Ran the program.  Label still there.  Rebuilt the program; re-ran.  Label still there.

Comment: Do you rebuild the solution after saving your changes?

Comment: @Anna Lear: Absolutely had to be asked. :)

Comment: yes, I do (extra characters to meet minimum requirement....)

Comment: There was a recent thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721645/visual-studio-wont-update-aspx-design-view) which may be related. FYI.

Comment: Are you running on IIS or the ASP.NET Dev server? If Dev server, I've had similar issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616389/asp-net-development-server-is-not-updating-changes-to-markup-code ... notice, no answer :-(

Comment: Yeah I'm just running it on the ASP.NET localhost.  Looks like you're having the same problem I am.  Will let you know if I hear anything.  Please do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like your are working on a **compiled website** project but have IIS running off the folder which contains the project you are working on in Visual Studio

When running like this there are strange issues that can occur where the site both has built classes in the Bin folder, as well as having dynamically compiled dll's in the ASP.Net temp folder and it really depends on the first line of your ASPX pages.

make sure the header of your aspx pages have **CodeFile='pagename.aspx.cs** if they are meant to be dynamically compiled and **CodeBehind='pagename.aspx.cs** is they are meant to be compiled by Visual Studio. You can't mix and match these two